# Excel macro to export the test cases along with the associated requirement Ids

Tags: excel, hp-alm, vba

I have a macro to export the test cases from the QC 11, but i am not able to get the requirement Id's which were mapped to them.

```
 For Each Node In NodesList
    Set TestTree = TreeMgr.NodeByPath(Node)
    Set TestFactory = TestTree.TestFactory
    Set TestList = TestFactory.NewList("") 'Get a list of all from node.

    'Iterate through all the tests.
    For Each TestCase In TestList
        Dim DesignStepFactory, DesignStep, DesignStepList
        Set DesignStepFactory = TestCase.DesignStepFactory
        Set DesignStepList = DesignStepFactory.NewList("")
  If DesignStepList.Count = 0 Then
            Sheet.Cells(Row, 1).Value = Trim(TestCase.Field("TS_TEST_ID"))
            Sheet.Cells(Row, 2).Value = Trim(TestCase.Field("TS_NAME"))
            Sheet.Cells(Row, 3).Value = Trim(TestCase.Field("TS_DESCRIPTION"))
            Sheet.Cells(Row, 4).Value = Trim(TestCase.Field("TS_RESPONSIBLE"))
            Sheet.Cells(Row, 5).Value = Trim(TestCase.Field("TS_SUBJECT").Path)
            Row = Row + 1
        Else
            For Each DesignStep In DesignStepList
                'Save a specified set of fields.
            Sheet.Cells(Row, 1).Value = Trim(TestCase.Field("TS_TEST_ID"))
            Sheet.Cells(Row, 2).Value = Trim(TestCase.Field("TS_NAME"))
            Sheet.Cells(Row, 3).Value = Trim(TestCase.Field("TS_DESCRIPTION"))
            Sheet.Cells(Row, 4).Value = Trim(TestCase.Field("TS_RESPONSIBLE"))
            Sheet.Cells(Row, 5).Value = Trim(TestCase.Field("TS_SUBJECT").Path)

                'Save the specified design steps.
                Sheet.Cells(Row, 6).Value = Trim(DesignStep.Field("DS_STEP_NAME"))
                Sheet.Cells(Row, 7).Value = Trim(DesignStep.Field("DS_DESCRIPTION"))
                Sheet.Cells(Row, 8).Value = Trim(DesignStep.Field("DS_EXPECTED"))
                Row = Row + 1
            Next
        End If
    Next
Next
```

Here i am getting the test case Id, Name, Description, designer and path. But i am not getting the Requirement Id which is mapped to It.

any help will be much appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since a test can cover more than one requirement, there is no single Requirement ID linked with the test. You can use the method [GetCoverList](http://alm-help.saas.hp.com/en/12.50/api_refs/ota/topic9158.html) from the Test Object to get a list of all requirements covered by the test—something like that:

```
Set RequirementList = TestCase.GetCoverList
```

Comment: Thanks Ronald. Exactly the one i am looking for. :)